# Shadow effect to Image/StackPanel in Windows Universal App

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

How can I add shadow effect in Windows universal app?

I have added Image into StackPanel. I want to add shadow effect to that control (StackPanel).

I am trying to do something like below image.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, i couldn't. There isn't any straight forward way to do it in Window Universal App.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the inspiration to arrive at something you like.

[image: Drop Shadow Effect]

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Margin="0,10">
        <Image Source="PinkSquare.png" Width="95" Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Image Source="PinkSquare.png" Width="95" Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Margin="0,10">
        <Image Source="GraySquare.png" Width="95" Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Image Source="PinkSquare.png" Width="95" Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Add borders, rounded corners, gradients, etc. to achieve the final look you like.